# Zero - IF receiver main limits

Tags: rf, signal, communication, modulation, receiver

I was reading [these](http://rfic.eecs.berkeley.edu/~niknejad/ee242/pdf/eecs242_lect3_rxarch.pdf) slides about receivers architectures, and I have some questions about Zero - IF receivers:

[image]

Precisely:

- Why is the spectrum around the carrier (i.e. the 2 "side bands") mirrored after the demodulation?
- From what I read it seems that this kind of receiver cannot work with signals with asymmetrical spectrum around the carrier frequency. But in theory, AM and FM spectrum are symmetrical. So, is that a limit for this receiver?

Comment: Because choosing the frequency called RF is incorrect. It needs to be slightly lower than that frequency. I’m answering this as a comment because I’m guessing you are trying to demodulate single sideband and I’m quite possibly very mistaken!!

Comment: @Andyaka - for a zero IF receiver you can put the LO at the receive frequency - it is required then that you have a complex mixer and demodulator that processes both I and Q to be able to separate the positive from negative frequencies.